# execvp does not get argument

Tags: arguments, execvp

My code is:

```
execvp(command, args);
```

args is `char* args[]`

command is `char* command`

for example for `ls -l`, command is ls and args is -l but why after executing

`execvp(command, args)`I get only result of `ls` not `ls -l`??

Answer (score 2):

The argument list *also* contains the name of the program.  Make sure that your `args` array contains both `"ls"` and `"-l"`.